# PHP cURL POST Jenkins job with parameters

Tags: php, windows, curl, jenkins, php-curl

Triggering `Jenkins job` via following `PHP` script:

```
<?php

$testrun_id = "1744";
$cmd = "curl -X POST http://build:f9280f75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/android-test/build --data-urlencode  json='{\"parameter\": [{\"name\":\"POST_RESULTS\", \"value\":\"true\"}, {\"name\":\"RUN_ID\", \"value\":\"{$testrun_id}\"}, {\"name\":\"CHECK_NAME\", \"value\":\"SampleAutomatedPlan\"}]}'";
exec($cmd,$result);

?>
```

This script runs successfully on **Mac** and the jenkins job does get triggered. How do I make this script to work on **Windows**? I am getting following error when I run above PHP script on **Windows**?

[image]

`curl is already installed on windows machine`. Also, is there a better way to do cURL in PHP? Looking at this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php, can someone point me towards an *example based on my curl command in the above PHP script*(for **Windows**)? An example based on the curl command in my script would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should check examples from here http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Bellow is the code for you case,

```
$url = "http://build:f9280f75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/android-test/buildWithParameters";     
$data = "POST_RESULTS=true&RUN_ID=".$testrun_id."&CHECK_NAME=SampleAutomatedPlan";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: not sure of how do i pass the parameters that i have in curl command like  json=..parameters and the `--data-urlencode` param

Comment: this is a single call with json params.

Comment: i updated my answer for your case to transfer data with POST,  as well

Comment: For every `curl_setopt` line, i am getting this error: `Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given`.

Comment: nvm, i fixed as the first parameter to all `curl_setopt` should be ch and not `curl` as we initially declared `ch for curl init`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type for JSON

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://build:f9280f75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/android-test/build --data-urlencode  json='{\"parameter\": [{\"name\":\"POST_RESULTS\", \"value\":\"true\"}, {\"name\":\"RUN_ID\", \"value\":\"{$testrun_id}\"}, {\"name\":\"CHECK_NAME\", \"value\":\"SampleAutomatedPlan\"}]}'";
```

Just make sure you don't have any mix matched values.

Comment: `<?php

$testrun_id = "1744";
$cmd = "curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://build:f9280f75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/android-test/build --data-urlencode  json='{\"parameter\": [{\"name\":\"POST_RESULTS\", \"value\":\"true\"}, {\"name\":\"RUN_ID\", \"value\":\"{$testrun_id}\"}, {\"name\":\"CHECK_NAME\", \"value\":\"SampleAutomatedPlan\"}]}'";
exec($cmd,$result);

?>` do I need to escape any character for -H param?

Comment: I have tried this: `...-H \"Content-Type: application/json\"` but it did not help and I get this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025656/nothing-was-submitted-error-from-jenkins-when-submitting-php-curl-to-build. Also if you check dinesh's answer above, I am getting `Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given`.