# PHP cURL POST Jenkins job with description parameter

Tags: php, curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am able to convert curl `POST jenkins job` call into php cURL. Here is my solution:

[PHP cURL POST Jenkins job with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157175/php-curl-post-jenkins-job-with-parameters/38157195#38157195)

which has something like:

```
$url = "http://build:f9280f75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/android-test/buildWithParameters";     
$data = "POST_RESULTS=true&RUN_ID=".$testrun_id."&CHECK_NAME=SampleAutomatedPlan";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Now I want to incorporate description field for the jenkins job so I can set it in beginning.

Here is what I am referring to: [How can I set Jenkins build description while triggering build via curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503736/how-can-i-set-jenkins-build-description-while-triggering-build-via-curl/36547510) which shows setting up of description via command line:

```
curl -v -X POST --data-urlencode "MyDescription=This is my desc" "http://[myServer]/job/[jobName]/buildWithParameters"
```

How to add such description parameter into above php curl method/call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like using post parameters, how about appending them onto the url?

```
$url = "http://build:f9280f75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/android-test/buildWithParameters?POST_RESULTS=true&RUN_ID=".$testrun_id."&CHECK_NAME=SampleAutomatedPlan&MyDescription=This+is+my+desc"
```